# How to read each revision of file using sharpsvn client using c#?

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

How to read each revision of file using sharpsvn client using c# ? Not the revision numbers but the content of the file in each revisions............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SvnClient.FileVersions for this like described in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829220/implement-a-faster-svn-cat-with-svnclient)

```
public void WriteRevisions(SvnTarget target, SvnRevision from, SvnRevision to)
{
    using(SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
    {
        SvnFileVersionsArgs ea = new SvnFileVersionsArgs 
            {
                Start = from,
                End = to
            };

        client.FileVersions(target, ea,
            delegate(object sender2, SvnFileVersionEventArgs e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.Revision);
                    e2.WriteTo(...);
                 });
    }
}
```