# Reading the contents of a file in sharpsvn

Tags: .net, sharpsvn

I'm trying to read the contents of a .csproj file using sharpsvn, but I seem to be always getting an empty file back.

Here is my code:

```
MemoryStream myOut = new MemoryStream();       
svnClient.Write(path, myOut))
return myOut.GetLibsFromCsproj();

private static string GetLibsFromCsproj(this MemoryStream csjpros)
{
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(csjpros);
    XElement projectNode = XElement.Load(tr);
    XNamespace msbuild = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
    var referenceNodes = projectNode.Descendants(msbuild + "ItemGroup").Descendants(msbuild + "Reference").ToString();
    return referenceNodes;
}
```

When my code gets to `XElement.Load(tr);`, it throws an error saying that root element is missing. It turns our that `myOut` is empty.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: this may be helpfull dude [The SharpSvn.SvnClient class has a GetList() function that works really well:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5679545/1239836)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you remember to reset the `MemoryStream` back to the beginning after writing into it? Try adding this line before the `return` statement:

```
myOut.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: Even adding this, myOut is no longer null, but it is empty. If I perform the same operation using a FileStream, it will write everything to the file just fine.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps this is helpful:

[How to read each revision of file using sharpsvn client using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1861968/863502)